# Vertical align of A elements inside LI

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with implementing a new design. While the anchor elements are aligned correctly in the old design, for some reason the anchor elements are aligned to the bottom in the new design with html/css regading the UL, LI and A part being exatly the same.

```
#treeview ul {
    padding-top: 3px;
}
#treeview ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#treeview ul li.active {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
}
#treeview ul li ul li {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
#treeview ul li a {
    color: #444444;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


<div id="treeview">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="assets/js/no-expand.png">
            <img class="icon" width="24" height="" src="assets/images/icons/icon_dance24x24.png">
            <a title="Essential" href="/index/night-clubs/essential/">Essential</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. clairesuzy did it for you this time; next time, try it yourself. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: There are probably 10 questions on the related list on the right that ask a very similar, if not the same question.

Comment: write display:block in your a tag

Comment: there are 10 questions about it, but the ones I looked at were solved by simply adding line-height property. In my case it works as expected in old design and does not matter what I do in the new one, it still does not work. The problem must be with the formatting of the container elements and if so, why?

Comment: adding display:block; does not work, instead it pushes the a to the next line below 2 images before it in the same li element.

Comment: I have also tried vertical-align: middle; together with line-height: 24px; as well as setting height of LI and/or A element to 24px

Comment: can you provide the HTML, too?

Comment: I just did. The css and html I posted are only part of the ul li and a, not the complete html/css where I think the actual problem lies. I think the full css/html of both of these designs are too long to post here. Perhaps I can post links to both versions, need to check if it is not against the rules.

Comment: In the new version your menu column is way too narrow. It's forcing the content to run to a new line. Also neither version works correctly in IE9.

Comment: there are menu elements in the new design that are not forced to run to a new line, you could use these as reference. The menu will be changed in a way that it will fit the narrow space (1 level deep only) so you don't have to worry about that. Besides, I'm using the same html/css as the old version, as you have pointed out, it doesnt fit the new style. Regarding IE9, well it looks like I need to not only find what is the problem with the new design, but also what is missing from both in order to make it work in all major browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
#treeview ul li * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This works :) I wonder if it works in IE9 as well. Also I still don't understand how it could work in the old design without this line. One of the css mysteries I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. It turned my vertical ul-li menu into horizontal one.